Why does my car only rotate and not move?
So I am following a tutorial by Pretty Fly Games on how to make a 2D racing game and I have added the car controller and the car input handler like he did in the video but my car cannot move forward, only rotate.
Here is a link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVHcOS1E5OQ&list=PLyDa4NP_nvPfmvbC-eqyzdhOXeCyhToko.
I have no idea what to do. It works normally on his video but not in my project.
Here is the Car Controller:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Car Settings")]
    public float accelerationFactor = 30.0f;
    public float turnFactor = 3.5f;

    //Local Variables
    float accelerationInput = 0;
    float steeringInput = 0;

    float rotationAngle = 0;

    //Components
    Rigidbody2D carRigidbody2D;

    //Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded.
    void Awake()
    {
        carRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    // Frame-rate independet for physics calculations
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ApplyEngineForce();

        ApplySteering();
    }

    void ApplyEngineForce()
    {
        //Crate a force for the engine
        Vector2 engineForceVector = transform.up * accelerationInput * accelerationFactor;

        //Apply force and pushes the car forward
        carRigidbody2D.AddForce(engineForceVector, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }

    void ApplySteering()
    {
        //Update the rotation angle based on input
        rotationAngle -= steeringInput * turnFactor;

        //Apply steering by rotating the car object
        carRigidbody2D.MoveRotation(rotationAngle);
    }

    public void SetInputVector(Vector2 inputVector)
    {
        steeringInput = inputVector.x;
        accelerationFactor = inputVector.y;
    }
}

And here is the car input handler:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Components
    CarController topDownCarController;

    //Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded.
    void Awake()
    {
        topDownCarController = GetComponent<CarController>();

    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = Vector2.zero;

        inputVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        inputVector.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        topDownCarController.SetInputVector(inputVector);
    }
}


I have no idea what to do: On the web page for that tutorial if you look under Source Code there is a URL which offers you the option to purchase access to the source code.

My lecturers have helped me with this.
The variable for the acceleration input was declared as accelerationInput and in the SetInputVector method, accelerationFactor is used instead of accelerationInput, causing the problem above.
I just had to change it to accelerationInput instead of accelerationFactor.
Silly mistake.
